# How do you prevent cursor change when using firefox browser?

Tags: 21.10

I have a custom cursor that I use off gnome-looks and when I open the firefox browser the cursor changes to the default black cursor. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: If you're using the Firefox snap, then there is no way to force it to use your custom cursor. Snaps are containerised and are limited to just the connections granted at the time of packaging, which for icons would be `gtk-common-*` or something like that. One option may be to use an `apt`-installed version of Firefox, which would have access to the custom icon library.

Comment: @matigo actually in 22.04 this does not even work as installing via apt still just grabs the snap unfortunately

Comment: @ConnerWithAnE one can [replace the Snap version with one from the Mozilla PPAs](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404401/1222991) if they prefer. It's *your* computer, after all ...

Comment: @matigo true true lol, I was just making a comment heh