# Firefox changes cursor arrow to a finger

Tags: firefox, mouse

How can I stop Firefox from changing my familiar and preferred cursor **arrow** to a likeness of someone else's **pointy finger**?

I have searched the settings in Firefox to find an option to stop this behaviour, but found none.  Is there some way in Ubuntu to prevent applications from changing the chosen cursor?

Using Firefox vl05.0.1 (64-bit) under Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64 with Linux 5.15.0-48-generic kernel.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1386628/how-do-you-prevent-cursor-change-when-using-firefox-browser

Comment: also it might be the website changing cursor with CSS, in which case you would need custom CSS to disable that.

Comment: @Esther  --  Thanks!  Looks like there is no easy solution for this behaviour.  Guess the pointy finger will win.